# Добавление объекта в объект

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Как добавить новый объект во вложенный products?

```
"ecommerce": {
    "add": {
        "products": [
            {
                "id": "5148",
                "name": "Компрессор K10",
                "price": 1500,
                "category": "Аксессуар",
                "quantity": 1
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: https://eval.in/916389 ?

Comment: @splash58 спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Перевести json строку в объект, добавить элемент, вернуть в строку.

```js
var testStr = '{"ecommerce": { "add": { "products": [{"id": "5148", "name": "Компрессор K10", "price": 1500, "category": "Аксессуар", "quantity": 1}]}}}';

var obj = JSON.parse(testStr);
var item = {"id": "666",
                "name": "штуцер 666",
                "price": 666,
                "category": "Средство уничтожения",
                "quantity": 1
            };
obj.ecommerce.add.products.push(item);
console.log(obj);

testStr = JSON.stringify(obj);
```